# Update ViewModel with ajax return result

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following Model

```
public class PersonViewModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname{ get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

My view looks something like this

```
@model Web.UI.PersonViewModel
<form class="form-horizontal" id="fuelux-wizard" method="post">
    @Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(p => p.Firstname).Placeholder("First name")
    @Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(p => p.Lastname).Placeholder("Last name")
    @Html.Bootstrap().Button().Class("btn btn-next").Text(Model.Id == Guid.Empty ? "Lets Start" : "Continue").HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "CreatePerson();" }).AppendIcon("fa fa-arrow-right")

</form>
```

Here is the js function which gets called when button is clicked

```
function CreateProposal() {

    // DO Ajax call to create the person
    $.ajax({ url: "CreatePerson", type: "POST", data: $('form').serialize() })
      .done(function () {

          $('.wizard').wizard('next');
      })
      .fail(function () {
          alert("Unable to save.");
          $("#personModal").modal("hide");
      });
}
```

In my controller I have a CreatePerson method too

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreatePerson(PersonViewModel personViewModel )
{            
    if(personViewModel .Id == Guid.Empty)
        personViewModel .Id = Guid.NewGuid();
     return Json(personViewModel );
}
```

How do I update the ViewModel of the view? The idea is to create a person and this will assign a new Guid to the model. The text in the button will differ when there is a Guid assigned as to when there is not.

Is there a way I can update the viewmodel with the returned ajax result?

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Does not seem any need to return the whole object (you already have the `Firstname` and `Lastname` in the view. Just return the Guid - `return Json(personViewModel.Id);` and then update the DOM in the `done()` callback. But not sure what you want to update?

Comment: The viewmodel.Id needs to be updated so the UI has a record of the ID for future operation on person

Comment: Or is it better to have a hidden field which holds the ID value? Then use js to update DOM and button text?

Comment: You would need to include a hidden input for the `Id` property, and then you could use `.done(function (data) { $('#Id').val(data); ...}` And I assume you would also change the button text to "Continue"?

Comment: Yehp. Looks like that would be my best option. thanks for helping me clear this up.

Comment: But why not just wait until the end of the wizard process to add the Guid (in the final save method)?

Comment: This is the first step and i only posted a sub set of the ui. Its part of a wizard, and on every step we want to save in case something happens so the user does not lose all their data they entered. Its quite a lengthy form to be filled in.

Comment: No problem - but your current code does not 'save' anything, it just assigns a value :)

Comment: Yehp again just a subset of the controller code, there is a service which creates the person and with a Guid in the actual application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need something like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="fuelux-wizard" method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(p => p.Firstname).Placeholder("First name")
    @Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(p => p.Lastname).Placeholder("Last name")
    @Html.Bootstrap().Button().Class("btn btn-next").Text(Model.Id == Guid.Empty ? "Lets Start" : "Continue").HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "CreatePerson();" }).AppendIcon("fa fa-arrow-right")

</form>

.done(function (data) {
    $('#Id').val(data.Id);
    $('.wizard').wizard('next');
})
```

You need to set the Id in the DOM. Think of the DOM as a data repository to store data from the server.